# Buffer read-back working depends on order of bind/map with DSA

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I am trying to perform read-back of SSBO data in OpenGL. For this I persistenly map the SSBO, but the following piece of code does not actually read back the written data from the example compute shader:

```
std::int32_t value = 12u;
GLuint ssbo = 0u;
glCreateBuffers(1u, &ssbo);
glNamedBufferStorage(ssbo, sizeof(value), &value, GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT);
const auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const std::int32_t*>(glMapNamedBuffer(ssbo, GL_READ_WRITE));

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo);
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);
glFinish();
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

std::memcpy(&value, ptr, sizeof(value));
printf("Value: %d\n", value);
```

The compute shader looks like this:

```
#version 460

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;
layout (std430, binding = 0) writeonly buffer resBuf { int res[]; };

void main()
{
    res[0] = 25;
}
```

The expected result of value should be 25, however I still get back the initial value of 12. The `glFinish` and `GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS` are just there to make sure that synchronization is not the issue.

Now, when I switch the order of `glMapNamedBuffer` and `glBindBufferBase`, I do get the correct read-back result - on an AMD GPU, that is. The read-back works in both cases on an Nvidia GPU.

I noticed that the documentation for `glBindBuffer` states that "The state of a buffer object immediately after it is first bound is an unmapped zero-sized memory buffer [...]". However, I am using DSA and there is little need to explicitly bind buffers for most operations, and `glCreateBuffers` also states that it creates a new buffer object "[...] as if it had been bound to an unspecified target."

Is this a bug with AMDs GL implementation or am I missing something? A simple workaround exists (simply bind the buffer to a bogus target), but I'd still like a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map a buffer persistently, you must *map the buffer persistently*. Allocating the buffer with the persistent flag only tells the system that you *could* map it persistently. Persistent mapping requires that the mapping call *itself* declare that the buffer is being mapped persistently.

So `glMapNamedBufferRange` (which is the function you need to use) needs to have the persistent flag on it.

Comment: Ahhh I knew I shouldn't have trusted the documentation of ```glMapBuffer``` which says that only read-write, read-only, write-only are allowed as access parameters... Thanks!

Comment: @IGarFieldI: They *are* the only bits allowed for that function. Persistent mapping requires using `glMapNamedBufferRange`; I forgot that point.